# How are "jti", "client_secret" and "exp" used to validate the "id_token"?

Tags: authentication, google-identity

I am doing this "tutorial"

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth

and it seems like I get the idea behind the concept.

Basically the user authenticates himself with google, gets a "certificate", that proves the he is he, and sends it to me, I validate that certificate with the help of google (public keys), and I can create the session for the user that belongs to the id in "sub", as I can be sure it was created by google ("iss"), for me ("aud"), not that long ago ("exp").

However, as I see, there is a 1 hour gap, when the token is valid.
I do not quite understand, why exactly 1 hour. I guess the reason is that the token **can be stolen** somehow (*how exactly?*), and then the user can be impersonated by an attacker. If that is the reason, why not 5 minutes, or 1, as it is a one time token, used only for login, just after the google login happened?

I also... I see a "jti" (token id), and a client secret.
When I created my credentials on google console, I also received a client_secret (along with the client_id). However I do not use it anywhere, what was its purpose?

And should I use the jti to make sure that nobody else wants to use the id_token? If that was the way to do it (I doubt it, it would lead to an ever-growing db of used "jti"s) why is that not mentioned anywhere in this tutorial?

I worked my way through the tutorial, and it is working - however these questions remain for me. So to sum it all up:

With all the work done, that was suggested by the tutorial...

**1.** Do I have to do anything with the "jti"? Do I leave a security gap, if I do not use it to anything?

**2.** Pretty much the same question for client secret - Do I leave a security gap by not doing anything with it? (*Why do I have it then?*)

**3.** What about the "exp"? I understand that the verify() method takes care of it, but do I have to do anything with it? (*If it matters, why 1 hour, why so long, if not, why not Long.maxValue or something?*)

I think based on what is written there I get what is happening, but also, I feel like not understanding **fully** what is happening, (all these fields and values) I might create a huge security gap - for me it seems like without all these, authentication might work just fine, but then why do they exist?

Comment: Very good question, one which I would also like to know the answer to.

Answer (score 2):

It is good to separate the mental picture of Google, FB etc registration from the standard login procedure. G and FB registering/login serves to shorten the registration procedure without entering user data and passwords and haggling with confirmation emails. It also shortens later consecutive logins without a need to enter both email and password. That's all, everything else goes the classical route.

Once we are registered and logged in with G, it sends JWT token to the frontend which we need to decode and store necessary data (username, avatar image, user id, jwt token). After that every page with protected data should send the usual request with the previously stored JWT token attached in the header. That procedure has nothing to do with the G and FB login anymore. On the server side (let's say Node server) we have to install JWT plugin like

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
```

then using it on every protected route to decode the token sent from the frontend and check whether it is valid or has it expired etc. Mentioned plugin above uses the secret key to check whether the token sent from the fronted is valid. That is the secret key Google gave to us.

Here is the sample procedure on the frontend (javascript), once we have token and want to fetch protected data from the server (Node.js):

```
fetch() {  
   let validToken = 'Bearer ' + this.logged; // frontend token

   axios.get('/userprofile/' + this.sellerId, {headers: {'Authorization': validToken}}).then((results) => {  
     this.raw = results.data; // store fetched data                     
   }).catch((e) => {
     console.log(e); // e.response is response error object
     if (e.response.status === 403) { // if token has expired (403 is Forbidden error)
     this.logged = null; // ..delete logged data, you may redirect the user to the login page
     }
});
```

On the server side we set JWT token check as a middleware between request and response:

```
// JWT middleware for checking jwt token sent from the browser
function verifyToken (req, res, next) {
    const bearerHead = req.headers['authorization'];  // get authorization sent via Axios object 'headers' from browser

    if (typeof bearerHead !== 'undefined') {  // if authorization is defined..
        const bearer = bearerHead.split(' '); // split 'Bearer' and token items..
        const bearerToken = bearer[1];  // take second item i.e. token value..
        req.token = bearerToken; // insert token into req object for use on protected API endpoints..
        next(); // and go to the next middleware/route (route is also middleware)
    } else {
        res.sendStatus(403); // send 'forbidden' status
    }
}
```

Finally we use this middleware on every protected route on the server (Node.js + Express, but principle is the same), we will decide whether to send or not necessary data based on token validness:

```
app.get('/hr/userprofile/:id', verifyToken, (req, res) => {
    let id = req.params.id;  // user id

    // verify token sent from the front-end page first
    jwt.verify(req.token, 'GOOGLE_SECRET_KEY', (err) => { // insert secret key obtained from G
        if (err) {
            res.sendStatus(403);  // if error send status: forbidden access  (page wil not be shown)
        } else {  // if authorization passed, execute everything else
            db.query("SELECT * FROM buyers WHERE buyer_id = ?", id, (err, results) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                res.send(results[0]);  // we are sending only one result
            });
        }
    });  // end of jwt.verify()
});
```

As per request, "jti" is a unique Google ID generated on every Google login. We can use this to check whether this particular user is logged in (we usually delete this data from the db on every logout), but since we use JWT token credentials check we actually don't need it.
"iss" is also there in case we have two users registered with the same email, one with the G login and another one with the classical user/password login. By using that data we can check which user to log in.
"client secret" use has been described above.

It is debatable whether using JWT is more secure than much simpler checking Google ID "jti" with one stored in the db which is not encoded when sent to the server. The fact is that the skilled con user with access to our browser can easily get both JWT and "jti" Google ID and use it on the same computer until JWT or "jti" doesn't expire (we would need to check "jti" for expiration on the server). Although expiration doesn't have much sense in the Oauth type of logging in, one can easily log in again by clicking G or FB login button, while in the ordinary login procedure, one has to know the username and password. I humbly think both are similarly secure for everyday use, but for stronger protection one needs 2-way auth. If someone has access to our browser while we are not present but logged in, there is not much we can do.

That's it

Answer (score 0):

You can get this detail here:

https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#CredentialResponse

HEADER

```
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": "f05415b13acb9590f70df862765c655f5a7a019e", // JWT signature
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

PAYLOAD

```
{
  "iss": "https://accounts.google.com", // The JWT's issuer
  "nbf":  161803398874,
  "aud": "314159265-pi.apps.googleusercontent.com", // Your server's client ID
  "sub": "3141592653589793238", // The unique ID of the user's Google Account
  "hd": "gmail.com", // If present, the host domain of the user's GSuite email address
  "email": "elisa.g.beckett@gmail.com", // The user's email address
  "email_verified": true, // true, if Google has verified the email address
  "azp": "314159265-pi.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "name": "Elisa Beckett",
                            // If present, a URL to user's profile picture
  "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/e2718281828459045235360uler",
  "given_name": "Elisa",
  "family_name": "Beckett",
  "iat": 1596474000, // Unix timestamp of the assertion's creation time
  "exp": 1596477600, // Unix timestamp of the assertion's expiration time
  "jti": "abc161803398874def"
}
```

Comment: so what is "jti" here?

Comment: @chuckieDub it's the JWT identifier